# How to load images one by one from database in GridView?

Tags: android, image, adapter, android-custom-view, android-gridview

I have a custom `GridView`, in which images are loading from the database. If I load all the images before setting the adapter,  then it takes too much time as there are more than 25 images (images are of size 30-35 kB each). If I load images one by one, then i need to set adapter after every image. And during loading of images one by one, when i scroll down, it moves to the top when new image is set...

I want my images to be load one by one, but if i scroll down then it should not move to the top when new image is loaded.

Comment: Consider using a LazyAdapter library, it loads images as and when they are in screen view: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/LazyAdapter.java

Comment: This is not the thing i want. Please read my question again.

Comment: Use AsyncTask to load the images, that way it won't affect the GridView each time image is loaded

Comment: i am using AsyncTask to load images. But as there are more than 20-25 images, so it takes lot of time to load. That's why I decided to load images one by one. But then i need to set adapter after every image. And during this, when i scroll down, it moves to the top when new image is set.

Comment: Dude, post your code, it's a bit of a guessing game here. This behaviour does not happen by default.

Answer (score 1):

I sounds like you aren't using a background task to load the adapter. I would create an asynctask that is inside of an adapter and then call a new instance of the asynctask on every getView() call. It will then load each image one at a time, but also shouldn't move the view every time an image is updated. You can also use the same technique to add in a placement image while they are being loaded.

Comment: Images are loading in asynctask. In the postExecute() method, I'am setting the adapter. But problem arises with the images. I am not finding any way to set images one by one without setting adapter again and again. 
your answer seems to be helpful. Can you please explain it more ?

Comment: When you create an adapter class you can override the getView which is called for each item that created in your GridView. While in this view you inflate the layout for that one item (which is probably just an ImageView) and then return the view. While in this method you can call a background task to load for that single item. When it goes through each item it will then pull them all separately in different tasks.